# How can I solve incompatible types error for my app in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I tried running a popup screen for an app I'm creating on android studio and I received a "incompatible types: cannot be converted to Context" error on the build.[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2SX.png)

Comment: replace 'this' with 'MainActivity.this'  and tell me if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
builder = AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

To refer to the instance of MainActivity, you have to use MainActivity.this.
The `this` keywork inside `onClickListener()` refers to the instance of the anonymous class.